# Which vector address is safer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Assuming a function needs a pointer to a vector of type T but when I have only a vector of vector of type T(type is not guaranteed to be a POD), is this

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> input;
auto selectedVectorPtr=&input[j];
```

safer than this

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> input;
auto selectedVectorPtr=&(input[j]);
```

also assuming input's scope doesn't end until that function which takes `selectedVectorPtr` as parameter.

My concerns(/misconceptions) are:

- does () create any temporary object? So is taking address of it is bad?
- does operator overloading of & or [] on type T have any effect on changing priority of operator precedence?
- what if vector(or both) is resized after getting address?

Comment: there are rules for operator precedence. This has nothing to do with safety, but correctness

Comment: The second is "safer" in the sense that you can't misunderstand it as `(&input)[j]` if you're in a hurry. Otherwise, they are equivalent.

Comment: Using the pointer in function must be something like `(*parameter)[k]` but it looks different ofcourse and I am also concerned about `*parameter[k]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`operator[]` has higher precedence then `operator&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) (postfix operators have the highest precedence), so it is evaluated first here, no parenthesis needed. There is no difference between `&input[j]` and `&(input[j])` here.

---

Alternative simpler syntax:

```
auto selectedVectorPtr = input.data() + j;
```

No need for `std::addressof` here either.

Comment: Does `()` create a temporary object or directly dereference array instead?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik `()` does not create a temporary object.

Comment: I don't see why the alternative way should be simpler. To me, `&input[j]` clearly says: "Get the address of the `j`th element". `input.data() + j` requires me to first read the member name, recall that it returns a pointer, recognize that `+ j` invokes pointer arithmetic on it, and then deduce that the result will be the address of the `j`th element... (Btw. I even prefer `&ptr[i]` over `ptr + i` in C code.)

Comment: @cmaster I prefer `pointer + index`. But thanks for sharing your mental process.

Comment: Why do you prefer `pointer + index`? What is your mental process for that?

Comment: @cmaster `&pointer[index]` used to be undefined behaviour when `index==size`, but `pointer + index` was well defined. They fixed that in later C++ standards, not sure about C.

Comment: Ah, well that would have been a good reason for `pointer + index`. I'm not sure what the C standard says about the possibility of `&*` yielding UB. I always just assumed that a compiler would do the right thing and just optimize both operations away (in C, `&*` always is a noop), the CPU never touches the object behind the pointer when it takes the address, after all. Maybe that was too careless on my part...

Comment: @cmaster Other than that, conceptually `&pointer[index]` is two operations (with possibly overloaded `operator&`), whereas `pointer + index` is one. This is why I prefer the latter.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - `&pointer[index]` is equivalent to `pointer + index`.  At one time, when the C++ standard was draft before 1998, calculating either gave undefined behaviour (assuming `pointer` points to the first element of a contiguous array of `size` elements).   However, that was changed well before the first C++ standard was ratified in 1998, so neither have undefined behaviour in any ratified C++ standard nor any draft standard since 1998.  There was never a time when one had undefined behaviour and the other didn't in C++.   In C, the behaviour remains undefined.

Answer (score 8):

The [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) dictates that `[]` is evaluated before the leading `&`. Hence, there is no difference in the two expressions.

As you were wondering about the safety implications of the snippets, there are two issues to consider for `&input[j]` (regardless of the outer parentheses):

- The index can be out of bounds, leading to undefined behavior. You might want to use the (possibly throwing but safer) [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and wrap that into a `try`-`catch` block.
- If you want to take the address of `T`, which is unknown a priori, [`operator &`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) could be overloaded for `T`. While this is evil in the first place, you can use [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to mitigate the possibility. Note that this is not necessary in your case, as you're taking the address of a `std::vector` instance.

Comment: Do you mean if somebody uses a class instead of float or double, it can lead to change in precedence of operations so operator & takes first priority?

Comment: No, you can't change the operator precedence by overloading. But you can change the meaning of `operator &` by overloading it for a user defined type.

Comment: Imho, people who overload `operator &` get precisely what they deserve... So, no need to use `std::address_of<>` ;-)    Good job mentioning the issues, +1 for that!

Answer (score 0):

`&input[j]` and `&(input[j])` will not have any difference. This is because `operator[]` have higher precedence then that of `operator&`.

So in both the cases it will evaluate to `&(input[j])`